# Custom Invitation in Zoom SDK is not working

Tags: android, intentfilter, zoom-sdk

I am integrating Zoom SDK in my Android project and I am facing an issue regarding custom invitation method. Actually, I tried a custom invitation mode in demo app and it is working fine but when I am trying to do the same in my existing project then its not working. I cannot see custom invitation method in existing project. I have changed package name in manifest folder and added code in config file. Please guide.

Manifest code:-
`<activity android:name="com.geniusstudent.smp.otherfeatures.MyInviteActivity"
            .........
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.geniusstudent.smp.intent.action.MeetingInvite" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Config code:-
    `<bool name="zm_config_invite_by_only_action_meeting_invite">false</bool>
    <string name="zm_config_conf_activity">com.geniusstudent.smp.inmeetingfunction.zoommeetingui.CustomZoomUIActivity</string>`

Answer (score 0):

**You can use ZOOM API for the invitation. I have done it with API using post method. You can try this way.**

```
https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/userId/meetings
userId= you can get it when you create a zoom id.
Bearer Token adds in API. After that, you can Invite with link anyone. 

{
  "topic": "Test 06",
  "type": 2,
  "start_time": "2020-08-29T16:19:22+0600",
  "duration": 30,
  "timezone": "Asia/Dhaka",
  "password": "Masum@",
  "agenda": "test meeting agenda",
  "recurrence": {
      "type":1
  }
```